# Mysql select query with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a Mysql table with the following data.

```
|ID | Date     | BillNumber|BillMonth | Amount | Name      |AccNum |
| 2 |2015-09-25| 454345    | 092015   | 135.00 |Andrew Good| 735976|
| 3 |2015-09-26| 356282    | 092015   | 142.00 |Peter Pan  | 123489|
| 4 |2015-08-11| 312738    | 082015   | 162.00 |Andrew Good| 735976|
| 5 |2015-07-12| 287628    | 072015   | 220.67 |Andrew Good| 735976|
| 6 |2015-06-12| 100756    | 062015   | 556.34 |Andrew Good| 735976|
```

What I wanted to achieve is to retrieve the data of Andrew Good with AccNum 735976 for the BillMonth of 092015, provided that the user can entry any of his BillNumber(past/current).

Comment: Your question really does not make sense.  Why do you want that particular record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reason that that row is of interest is because it is the latest of his rows, try:

```
select  *
from    tbl t
where   name =  (  select   name
                   from     tbl
                   where    billnumber = 100756 -- can be any of his
                )
    and date =  (  select   max(date)
                   from     tbl x
                   where    x.name = t.name
                )
```

(the billnumber can be any of his)